# Не работает backgroung-image

Tags: css, img, background-image

У меня не работает backgrounde image, я знаю что я указал неправильно путь. Я уже пересмотрел все форумы с этим вопросом и не один из советов не помог[image: мое расположение файлов]

```css
body{
    background-image: url("../background.jpg");
    background:no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

- Если файл лежит в той же папке, то достаточно прописать только имя файла;
- Общим свойством `background`, Вы затираете то, что указали в `background-image`;
- Задайте высоту для тега `<body>`, если он пустой.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url('background.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!, работает.

Comment: Я б посоветовал указывать `min-height: 100vh`)